# JSON Google maps geocode is not working

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I'm searching for a fix since two days now. So I hope that someone is able to help me with this:

I get adresses by google api and I know that the result page of google is fine. But should get saved into the database and that doesn't work. There seems to be an mistake within the following code. I would be happy if someone findes it... ;)

Thanks a lot!

```
function reverse_geocode($latitude, $longitude) {
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&sensor=false";
$result = wp_remote_get($url);
$json = json_decode($result['body']);
foreach ($json->results as $result)
{
    foreach($result->address_components as $addressPart) {
        if((in_array('locality', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types)))
            $city = $addressPart->long_name;
        else if((in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types)))
            $state = $addressPart->long_name;
        else if((in_array('country', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types)))
            $country = $addressPart->long_name;
    }
}

if(($city != '') && ($state != '') && ($country != ''))
    $address = $city.', '.$state.', '.$country;
else if(($city != '') && ($state != ''))
    $address = $city.', '.$state;
else if(($state != '') && ($country != ''))
    $address = $state.', '.$country;
else if($country != '')
    $address = $country;

return $address;
}
```

And then it gets (normally) written into the DB:

```
    function geolocation_save_postdata($post_id) {
  // Check authorization, permissions, autosave, etc
  if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['geolocation_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__)))
    return $post_id;

  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;

  if('page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
        return $post_id;
  } else {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) 
        return $post_id;
  }

  $latitude = clean_coordinate($_POST['geolocation-latitude']);
  $longitude = clean_coordinate($_POST['geolocation-longitude']);
  $address = reverse_geocode($latitude, $longitude);
  $public = $_POST['geolocation-public'];
  $on = $_POST['geolocation-on'];

  if((clean_coordinate($latitude) != '') && (clean_coordinate($longitude)) != '') {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_latitude', $latitude);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_longitude', $longitude);

    if(esc_html($address) != '') {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_address', $address);
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_address', 'unbekannter Adresse | Koordinaten: '.$latitude.' Breite, '.$longitude.' Länge');
        }
    if($on) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_enabled', 1);

        if($public)
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_public', 1);
        else
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_public', 0);
    }
    else {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_enabled', 0);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_public', 1);
    }
  }

  return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: What do the contents of $address look like at the end of the function?

Comment: I added the next function to the question above...

Comment: I think we need more information - where does it go wrong, is there an error, does it write the wrong values to the DB, or nothing at all?

Comment: It seems that it doesn't find any results for $address.
It always saves "unbekannte Adresse [...]" which is set as "else" here:

`if(esc_html($address) != '') {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_address', $address);
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'geo_address', 'unbekannter Adresse | Koordinaten: '.$latitude.' Breite, '.$longitude.' Länge');
        }`

Thank you!

Comment: @duncan It would be great if you could take another look to this. Are there more information necessary?! :)

Comment: I don't know PHP, but can you log what you get back in $json ?